# How do you correctly implement DateTime in your specific class constructor?

Tags: c#

I have a class called "Employee" with the following variables:

```
private string name;
private DateTime birthday;
private DateTime dateOfEmployment;
private string address;
private double salary;
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
public Employee(string name = "defaultName", DateTime birthday = new DateTime(), DateTime dateOfEmployment = new DateTime(), string address = "defaultAddress", double salary = 1000)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.dateOfEmployment = dateOfEmployment;
    this.address = address;
    this.salary = salary;                    
}
```

How do I correctly implement the DateTime so that I dont have to use 'Convert.ToDateTime()' everytime I create a new 'Employee'-Object?
Is there some kind of 'best practise' I can follow or do you have any tips on how to use DateTime in this case?

I am new to C# (as you can see) and I want to learn how to use DateTime. Just saving the Time in a string is not an option for me.

Comment: Like other structs/classes, `DateTime` has [a number of constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2). You would create it however makes sense for your application.

Comment: It sounds like you have some problem with code that *is not shown in the post*. So far it is very unclear what problems you may have passing `DateTime` values to the `Employee` constructor and how " saving the Time in a string" is related to code shown (which clearly shows `DateTime` to store date properties).

Comment: Did you want to make `new Employee("asd", "2019-04-16")` work?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Thats exactly what I want to do! How can I make this work? Everytime I try to set something like "2017/05/04" I have to use the 'Convert.ToDateTime()' method. Thats annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Storing the employee dates as a DateTime is correct, so you are on the right track.

About your employee constructor: It looks like you are trying to default all of the values. Is this really what you want to do? Typically, this kind of constructor would force the caller to specify all of the values, and it would be up to the caller to send in an already created DateTime.

If you really want to default a date time, consider using the readonly value `DateTime.MinValue`

Alternately you can use one of the constructors that come with DateTime. For a birthday, your most likely candidate is `var birthday = new DateTime(year, month, day);`

As far as a "best practice" the DateTime should be created elsewhere(the UI perhaps) and sent into your constructor as a parameter without a default.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! Yes, I want to assign a default value to all variables for no particular reason. Its just for learning purposes. I will add the (year, month, day) part then. But unfortunately I do not understand the last part. Where should the DateTime be created?

Comment: "DateTime … sent into your constructor as a parameter without a default" - this is really questionable suggestion as it is perfectly fine to have no information on birthday in many cases... Clearly one would use `DateTime? birthday = null` in such case (rather than `.MinValue`)… but implying that default parameters is not "the best practice" is strange (in otherwise good answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can just incorporate `DateTime.Parse` into your ctor:

```
public class Employee
{
    private static readonly string[] SupportedDateFormats = new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", /* add more as you see fits */};

    public string name;
    public DateTime birthday;
    public DateTime dateOfEmployment;
    public string address;
    public double salary;

    public Employee(string name = "defaultName", DateTime birthday = new DateTime(), DateTime dateOfEmployment = new DateTime(), string address = "defaultAddress", double salary = 1000)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.dateOfEmployment = dateOfEmployment;
        this.address = address;
        this.salary = salary;   
    }
    public Employee(string name = "defaultName", string birthdayText = null, string dateOfEmploymentText = null, string address = "defaultAddress", double salary = 1000)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.salary = salary;

        // or, you can use your language/country-speficic culture 
        // if you need to parse text like, "April 16, 19" or "16 Juin 19" (french)
        var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        this.birthday = string.IsNullOrEmpty(birthdayText)
            ? new DateTime()
            : DateTime.TryParseExact(birthdayText, SupportedDateFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var birthdayValue)
                ? birthdayValue : throw new FormatException($"Invalid `{nameof(birthdayText)}` format: {birthdayText}");
        this.dateOfEmployment = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateOfEmploymentText)
           ? new DateTime()
           : DateTime.TryParseExact(dateOfEmploymentText, SupportedDateFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateOfEmploymentValue)
               ? dateOfEmploymentValue : throw new FormatException($"Invalid `{nameof(dateOfEmploymentText)}` format: {dateOfEmploymentText}");
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
new Employee(birthdayText: "1919-04-16"); // Employee { ..., birthday: 1919-04-16, dateOfEmployment: 0001-01-01, ... }
new Employee(birthdayText: "2019-04-99"); // FormatException: Invalid `birthdayText` format: 2019-04-99
```